# Freezing discriminator layers in a GAN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement a [SimGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07828) in Keras, but I believe the question is more generally related to GANs and freezing layers.

As I understand it I need three models:

1. The *refiner*, which processes a synthetic image to make it more realistic. (In other GAN architectures, this might be the *generator*, which accepts random noise.)
2. The *discriminator*, which processes an image and classifies it as synthetic or real.
3. A combined model which passes the synthetic image through the refiner, and then the refined image into the discriminator.

In the combined model, we want the discriminator layers to be *frozen*, so that when the combined model is trained, we update only the refiner layers.

Separately, we train the discriminator-only model, where obviously the layers should not be frozen. The layers of the discriminator model and the combined model should share weights so that both get updated.

Here's what I have so far:

```py
refiner_model = make_refiner_model(input_shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))
discriminator_model = make_discriminator_model(input_shape=refiner_model.output_shape[1:])

# create combined model with frozen discriminator layers
synthetic_image_tensor = layers.Input(refiner_model.input_shape[1:])
refiner_model_output = refiner_model(synthetic_image_tensor)
combined_output = discriminator_model(refiner_model_output)

combined_model = models.Model(
    inputs=synthetic_image_tensor,
    outputs=[refiner_model_output, combined_output],
    name='combined'
)
```

How do I freeze the discriminator layers in the combined model *without* freezing them in the discriminator-only model?

---

The [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers) explicitly suggests the following:

```py
refiner_model.compile(...)
discriminator_model.compile(...)

discriminator_model.trainable = False
combined_model.compile(...)
```

But then when I print out `discriminator_model.summary()`, the number of parameters has doubled?

```
Total params: 151,812
Trainable params: 75,906
Non-trainable params: 75,906
```

Then I'll get [warnings about changing `.trainable` without recompiling](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8585), and eventually fail with [this error](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28287).

Comment: I believe that `.compile() -> .trainable -> .summary()` presents incorrect results, so that's a bit of a red herring.